# My QUERY google sheet function does'nt work?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, formula

This is the QUERY used into my google sheet:

```
=QUERY(control!A1:AF; "SELECT G, SUM(I), MIN(L), MIN(K), SUM(P), SUM(P)/SUM(Y), SUM(Y), SUM(Y)/"&credit!$B$10&" WHERE A='open' GROUP BY G ORDER BY SUM(Y) DESC LABEL SUM(I) 'shares', MIN(L) 'avg_price', MIN(K) 'current_price', SUM(P) 'net_PL_open', SUM(Y) 'cost', SUM(P)/SUM(Y) 'net_PL_%', SUM(Y)/"&credit!$B$10&" 'invest_%'";1)
```

The QUERY above present an error:

> "Não foi possível analisar a string de consulta para Função QUERY parâmetro 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "," ", "" at line 1, column 271. Was expecting one of: <STRING_LITERAL> ... "*" ... "+" ... "-" ... "/" ... "%" ..."

Any idea about what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
={"rewrite this"\ "shares"\ "avg_price"\ "current_price"\ 
  "net_PL_open"\ "net_PL_%"\ "cost"\ "invest_%"; 
 QUERY(QUERY(control!A1:AF; 
 "select G,sum(I),min(L),min(K),sum(P),sum(P)/sum(Y),sum(Y),sum(Y)/"&credit!B10&" 
  where A='open' 
  group by G 
  order by sum(Y) desc"); "offset 1"; 0)}
```